# Why should I use reset($arr) instead of $arr[0] in php to yield the first element of an Array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm new to php and was wondering why one would use [reset($arr)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) over $arr[0] to yield the first element of an array. Are there any benefits over one vs. the other?

Comment: `reset` is usually used when dealing with internal pointers manually in a loop and mostly done when elements' indexes are being manipulated.

Comment: `reset` works with associative arrays too. While `$arr[0] ` works only numeric array